# Как установить систему Windows на ноутбук с загрузочной флешки?

Tags: windows

Если можно напишите, пожалуйста, поэтапно. как Вы это делаете.
Устанавливаемая система : Windows 8.1

Еще хотелось бы сделать два раздела на жестком диске, чтобы избежать утери файлов при переустановке системы и подобного рода проблем, например, чтобы на одном разделе хранились бы программы, на другом - различные файлы.

С помощью каких программ можно так фрагментировать диск?
Это ведь лучше делать до установки операционной системы? 
Опишите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать.

Загрузочная флешка есть.

Comment: а какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к программированию? Кроме того, если вы погуглите, то увидите, что интернет забит инструкциями на эту тему

Comment: Интернет просто завален видео/текстовыми мануалами! Неужели легче тут зарегаться и оформить вопрос, вместо того, что бы вбить около 5 слов в гугл и открыть ссылку?

Comment: Всё давно уже сделала, спасибо всем ответившим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
1. Установите программы [UltraISO](http://ultraiso.co)
2. Откройте програм и нажмите "Записать образ Жесткого диска..."[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. И нажмите "Записать"!

Answer (score 4):

Кроме UltraISO Есть стандартная программа от мелкософтоцев [Windows7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool-Installer-en-US](http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=wudt&DownloadId=96313&FileTime=129048694816630000&Build=20999)  Windows USB/DVD Download Tool Подходит для создания Vista/win7/win8/Win8.1/Win10/Win2008/Win2012/

Она очень простая в обращении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаем и жмем на кнопку "Browse"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Указываем путь к образу диска и жмем "Next"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликаем по кнопке "USB device"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И выбираем нужную для нас флеш карту
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаем "Begin coping" дожидаемся 100% и наша загрузочная флешка готова!! (форматирует флешку программа сама автоматически)

По поводу 2й части вопроса:
Разбить диск следует до установки Windows из бесплатных программных продуктов я рекомендую [MiniTool® Partition Wizard](http://software-files-a.cnet.com/s/software/14/01/95/72/pwfree9.exe?token=1431571483_54419014c496ffc0299968fb062ecb50&fileName=pwfree9.exe)

также на сайте разработчика есть 
[Partition Wizard Bootable CD](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html#) - образ загрузочного диска

P.S. По поводу как устанавливать и разбивать диск. То в данном контексте это проблематично делать, скорее надо видео урок делать, а не пост со статьей по этому пригласите кого не будь, кто уже устанавливал операционные системы и запоминайте как это делать.

Answer (score 1):

Для разбиения диска корректнее будет использовать утилиту DISKPART (инструкция [по ссылке](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)), которая и так присутствует на записанном вами установочном диске. Консоль можно вызвать при помощи нажатия комбинации Shift+F10 на этапе установки системы.

Но вообще при установке Windows есть вполне гуёвые менюшки для разбиения диска, можно использовать их. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также можно разбить диск после установки через гуй Disk Management/Управление дисками или всё тот же DISKPART.